# How to structure MVC controllers when writing a RESTful API

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller, restful-url

I'm currently implementing a RESTful API using an MVC framework. I have set up some controllers which allow me to access data on some general collections, for example:

```
GET /products
GET /products/1
GET /users
GET /users/1
```

My controller is structured so that it has a method for `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, and `delete()` which match up the the HTTP verb made by the incoming request. Then in the `get()` function for example I check if the id is present and workout whether to get a single object or an array, like this:

```
public function action_get()
{
    $id = (int) $this->request->param('id');
    if (empty($id))
    {
        // return an array of everything
    }
    else
    {
         // return a specific object
    }
}
```

This all works fine. However the next step is to have a relationship to my products or users, so for example:

```
GET /users/1/transactions
GET /users/1/transactions/1
```

Now obviously I could add this into the `action_get()` method above but that would make it bloated. So should I create a separate controller for transactions and pass the user id as a parameter with some clever routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `users` can have many `transactions` right? So it is better to have a separate controller for transactions. Just like you did for your users do it for transactions. [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

```
GET /transactions
GET /transactions/1
```

This way you'll not only benefit the simplicity of `GET` in your controller but also you can structure your controller to accept `POST`, `DELETE`, and `PUT`.

Comment: Well yes this works in terms of simplicity but in terms of RESTful endpoint design which of these is better: `GET /users/1/transactions` or `GET /transactions?user=1`

Comment: Second one. I recommend you watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/embed/o-4mibDn_aU) and read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/).